nextjs cookies not saved in browser
I am having issue saving the cookies.
I am using two middlewares that I chain in order to: redirect to the right language and save the locale as a cookie / then to get the user's session with supabase client.
What I was expecting is:
1/ if the user navigates to an url containing the locale, then we save this locale in the cookies and we proceed directly to the next middleware handling the session. If he navigates to another page, the locale should remain the same
2/ if the user navigates to an url not containing the locale, we redirect the user to the same url prefixed with the locale (saved in the cookies if it is saved) or "en". This should bring the user to 1/
Actual behaviour with issue: The second one. If I reset the cache, and "fr" is initially saved in the cookies, then it's never updated. If the user refreshes the page with "en" as locale, and then clicks on a link, he's redirected to an url with "fr" as locale.
export async function updateSession(request) {

  let supabaseResponse = NextResponse.next({
    request,
  });

  const supabase = createServerClient(
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL,
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY,
    {
      cookies: {
        getAll() {
          return request.cookies.getAll();
        },
        setAll(cookiesToSet) {
          cookiesToSet.forEach(({ name, value }) =>
            request.cookies.set(name, value),
          );
          supabaseResponse = NextResponse.next({
            request,
          });
          cookiesToSet.forEach(({ name, value, options }) =>
            supabaseResponse.cookies.set(name, value, options),
          );
        },
      },
    },
  );


  const {
    data: { user },
  } = await supabase.auth.getUser();


  return supabaseResponse;
}


function getLocale(request) {
  // Checks if language already stored in the cookie
  if (request.cookies.has(cookieName)) {
    return request.cookies.get(cookieName).value;
  }

  const acceptLang = request.headers.get("Accept-Language");
  if (!acceptLang) return defaultLocale;
  const headers = { "accept-language": acceptLang };
  const languages = new Negotiator({ headers }).languages();
  return match(languages, locales, defaultLocale);
}


export function languagesMiddleware(request) {
  const { pathname } = request.nextUrl;

  const isApiRoute = pathname.startsWith("/api/") || pathname === "/api";
  if (isApiRoute) return NextResponse.next({ request });

  const pathnameHasLocale = locales.some(
    (locale) => pathname.startsWith(`/${locale}/`) || pathname === `/${locale}`,
  );
  if (pathnameHasLocale) {
    request.cookies.set(cookieName, pathname.split("/")[1]);
    return NextResponse.next({ request });
  }

  const locale = getLocale(request);
  request.nextUrl.pathname = `/${locale}${pathname}`;
  const newResponse = NextResponse.redirect(request.nextUrl);
  newResponse.headers.set("X-Redirect-Path", request.nextUrl.pathname);
  return newResponse;
}


export async function middleware(request) {
  const languageResponse = languagesMiddleware(request);
  if (languageResponse?.headers?.get("X-Redirect-Path"))
    return languageResponse;

  return await updateSession(request);
}

The cookies seemed to be saved correctly since at the end of updateSession function, when I console.log supabaseResponse and I get:
{
  cookies: ResponseCookies {},
  url: '',
  body: null,
  bodyUsed: false,
  headers: {
  x-middleware-next: '1',
  x-middleware-override-headers: 'accept,accept-encoding,accept-language,connection,cookie,host,sec-ch-ua,sec-ch-ua-mobile,sec-ch-ua-platform,sec-fetch-dest,sec-fetch-mode,sec-fetch-site,sec-fetch-user,upgrade-insecure-requests,user-agent,x-forwarded-for,x-forwarded-host,x-forwarded-port,x-forwarded-proto',
  x-middleware-request-accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
  x-middleware-request-accept-encoding: 'gzip, deflate, br, zstd',
  x-middleware-request-accept-language: 'en-US,en;q=0.9,fr-FR;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7,en-GB;q=0.6',
  x-middleware-request-connection: 'keep-alive',
  x-middleware-request-cookie: 'locale=en',
  x-middleware-request-host: 'localhost:3002',
  x-middleware-request-sec-ch-ua: '"Google Chrome";v="129", "Not=A?Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="129"',
  x-middleware-request-sec-ch-ua-mobile: '?0',
  x-middleware-request-sec-ch-ua-platform: '"macOS"',
  x-middleware-request-sec-fetch-dest: 'document',
  x-middleware-request-sec-fetch-mode: 'navigate',
  x-middleware-request-sec-fetch-site: 'none',
  x-middleware-request-sec-fetch-user: '?1',
  x-middleware-request-upgrade-insecure-requests: '1',
  x-middleware-request-user-agent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/129.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
  x-middleware-request-x-forwarded-for: '::1',
  x-middleware-request-x-forwarded-host: 'localhost:3002',
  x-middleware-request-x-forwarded-port: '3002',
  x-middleware-request-x-forwarded-proto: 'http'
},
  ok: true,
  redirected: false,
  status: 200,
  statusText: '',
  type: 'default'
}

